# NPM do NodeJS não funciona

Tags: javascript, node.js, aplicação-web

Gente, instalei o node normalmente e adicionei á variável de ambiente; fiz algumas operações matemáticas para testar e funcionou. Quando tentei instalar módulos (socket.io e express) não funcionou, mesmo executando como administrador. Tentei verificar o comando para testar se o npm está instalado, mas recebo como retorno um erro. O comando foi para verificar a versão do npm: `npm -v` e isso também não funcionou com node mesmo ele estando instalado e funcionando: `node -v`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Estás a fazer os comandos mal. Não entres no modo node... faz "node -v" e não "node [enter] -v".

Comment: Execute as funções `npm` fora do command do node. Apenas abra seu `cmd` e insira o comando `npm ...`. Se não fui claro, fique a vontade para questionar.

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente. Funcionou. Realmente estava a executar os comandos de forma errada, mas agora o problema é outro: quando tentei instalar o socket.io ocorreu vários erros.

Comment: Acredito que essa pergunta foi resolvida então :) Se precisar de ajuda com os outros erros, pode postar novas perguntas e [veja o que fazer ao ter uma pergunta respondida](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Ivan, o ideal seria que você abrisse outra pergunta para falar sobre esses erros que você está tendo ao instalar o pacote. Apenas para manter a organização do site, e quando for abrir a próxima pergunta sobre o erro tente copiar todo o log de instalação, apenas aquela imagem ali não ajuda muito, precisaria saber o que estava escrito mais acima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só está executando no lugar errado seu comando. O `npm` é o [Gerenciador de Pacotes do Node](http://nodebr.com/o-que-e-a-npm-do-nodejs/), você não precisa "iniciar" o `node` (*node + enter no seu console*) para utilizá-lo.
Abra o `command` e digite `npm -v` diretamente na linha de comando.

```
C:\Users\pfortesc>npm -v
2.14.4
```

[image]

Como explicado pelo @Sergio, da maneira que você estava fazendo o `node` estava tentando encontrar a variável `npm`, como ela não existe, a exceção foi disparada.

Comment: Realmente. Estava a fazer errado.

Answer (score 2):

Estás a correr em modo `node` e não deve ser assim.

Quando escreves somente `node` entras num modo de JavaScript, ou seja estás numa consola de JavaScript. Aí quando escreves `npm` ele vai interpretar como uma variável JavaScript e diz que não está defenida...

Usa diretamente na consola:

```
$ npm -v
$ # ou
$ node -v
```

Comment: Entendi. Realmente estavas a fazer errado. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

`node` e `npm` são dois programas separados e você estava tentando executar o `npm` de dentro do `node`, o que claramente não iria funcionar. Ou seja, basta você executar o `npm` como um comando normal no Command Prompt do Windows.

Ao invés de fazer isso:

```
C:\Users\zignd>node
> npm -v
ReferenceError: npm is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:132:27)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:109:10)
```

Faça isso:

```
C:\Users\zignd>npm -v
2.10.1
```